# How to correctly use alert with apply in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, reflection

I wonder whether the JavaScript alert function in the browser
needs the document as this parameter or not. So what is the
correct call via apply?

```
/* Variant 1 */
alert.apply(null, ["Hello World!"])

/* Variant 2 */
alert.apply(window, ["Hello World!"])
```

An answer to the above question might also discuss bind
and call, but I would be already happy if somebody could
enlighten the apply case.

**Edit 25.06.2021:**
It seems that alert is not "normal", I get inside some fiddle:

```
/* Variant 3 */
alert.apply(document, ["Hello World!"]);
-->
Error: 'alert' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234198/discussion-between-mostowski-collapse-and-felix-kling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of these:

```
alert.apply(window,    ["Hello word"]);
alert.apply(null,      ["Hello world"]);
alert.apply(undefined, ["Hello world"]);
```

The reason you can use any of those is that `alert` is (effectively) defined in loose mode,¹ which means it can't have `null` or `undefined` as `this`; so if you call it passing `null` or `undefined` as `this`, the default `this` (`window` on browsers, roughly) is used instead.

You can't use `document` because [per specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert-noargs) `alert` uses `this` (to see whether it can show dialogs for the window). So it needs `this` to be the window, not the document.

---

¹ *loose mode* (also called *sloppy mode* by people who don't care about parallel construction) is the opposite of *strict mode*. Code is in loose mode unless you use modules, `class`, or `"use strict";`.

Comment: I had already forgotten that the global object is used when `null` or `undefined` are passed in non-strict mode...

Comment: Is loose mode portable, or some legacy? Do you know by chance? (Ok, I see, non-strict, so wouldn't work with type="module"?)

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse: Whether or not a function is strict depends on in which environment it is defined, not where it is called. Presumably the global/host environment is always non-strict, otherwise the Web would probably break.

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse - I don't know what yo mean by "portable." Yes, it's legacy. All code prior to ES5 was loose mode, so it had to remain the default. ES5 introduced strict mode which improves several aspects of JavaScript, not least by getting rid of [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).